# Invoke a tag library on anchor link click event without form refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsp, taglib

I've a scenario where I've to make a call to Grails/ jsp taglib in order to get data and feed to the google charts.  Here is my GSP code.

```
<a href="#empTab" onclick="initializeData();">
```

$(document).ready(function(){
    initializeData()

```
function initializeData(){
    var chartsData = {}
   chartsData.frameDelayVariation = <emp:metrics name="${name}"  timeInterval="${timeInterval}" />
}
});
```

When I first come to the page,it invokes taglib and  when I click on HREF link, the JS function get called but taglib not being invoked...

So is there any way that I could achieve this by Jquery without form submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ajax supported grails remoteLink tag to invoke a controller and reloading all the google charts script libraries onSuccess attribute so that all my google charts will be reloaded with the new Json Data.